# constexpr std::optional reset

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, stdoptional

I was reviewing the interface for the C++-17 `std::optional` class template and noticed that the [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/reset) and [`assignment`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D) from `nullopt` are not marked as constexpr.

Was this an oversight or is there a reason that this operation cannot be marked constexpr?

Comment: If that were true, no assignment operator could be marked constexpr. `std::optional` has several such assignment operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a reason, which was that [[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2.10) had previously forbid:

> an assignment expression or invocation of an assignment operator ([class.copy]) that would change the active member of a union;

That restriction no longer exists as a result of [P1330: Changing the active member of a union inside constexpr](https://wg21.link/p1330), which makes all of these things much easier to implement (the paper literally just removes the bullet point I quoted above).

The reason that `optional`'s copy and move assignment (but none of the other assignments) were `constexpr` was because they can just be defaulted for trivial types.

Comment: Is there a paper to make `optional`s functions constexpr now that we have P1330?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Not that I'm aware of - want to write it?

Comment: Follow ups: With that, it's possible to implement an entirely `constexpr` `std::optional`, correct? And why does the standard implementation use a `union` in the first place (e.g. in favor of `std::aligned_storage` or just raw bytes)?

Comment: @m8mble Yes. And can't use any kind of `reinterpret_cast` in constexpr.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Alright, [now there is](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2231r0.html).

Comment: We don't deserve you Barry. You're amazing :)